# Sony WH-1000XM2's microphone doesn't work with KDE Plasma 5 over bluetooth

Tags: sound, bluetooth, kde, microphone

[Lenovo B71-80](https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/lenovo/b-series/b71-80/) + [Sony WH-1000XM2](https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/wh-1000xm2).

This combination connects via bluetooth, headphone speakers work, but not the microphone.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

My system is KDE neon 5.18.